# Need to create data frame from list, but most terms turn into ones

Tags: r

I am trying to take a list of data frames that I had just created and unlist, so that I can create one giant data frame. However, somewhere in the for loop, my pvalues, lengths, and samples turn into factors, even though when I look at them individually, they are characters. I suppose them being factors is what makes the terms one when I try to unlist. How do I fix this so that the real terms are revealed, not ones?

Code:

```
for(i in 1:24) {
  l <- length(olap[[i]])
  for (j in 1:l) {
    sub_olap <- as.data.frame(mcols(subsetByOverlaps(all_list, olap[[i]][j])))
    chrdata[[j]] <- data.frame(median(sub_olap$log2Ratio),
                   paste0(sub_olap$pvalue, collapse = ","),
                   paste0(sub_olap$length, collapse = ","),
                   paste0(sub_olap$sample, collapse = ","))
    colnames(chrdata[[j]]) <- c("med_log2Ratio", "pvalue", "length", "sample")
  }
  mdata[[i]] <- chrdata
}

data.frame(matrix(unlist(mdata[[1]]), nrow = 81))
```

Comment: The function `data.frame` has an argument `stringsAsFactors` that defaults to `TRUE`. This may be the reason that your values are being converted to factors. Try setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your call to `data.frame`.

Comment: I don't understand all that you're trying to do, but I see you're coercing vectors into characters to fit them in a `data.frame`. That's not necessary, you can put a vectors a data.frame column

Comment: OK now I see, `unlist` is recursive by default, and `mdata` is a list of `data.frames` and `data.frames` are lists, so you're unlisting everything when you want just one level. call `unlist` with parameter `recursive` set to FALSE

Comment: It's very dirty to call matrix on top of this though,if data types were different you'd have issues, with factors as well. try `do.call(rbind,unlist(mdata[[1]],recursive=FALSE))`