# Nested for loop not working properly R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying trying to create a nested for loop, but somehow, the dimensions of `mdata` are mostly incorrect. For instance, the values for `length(mdata[[1:5]])` are almost all 81, when they should be 81, 50, 60, etc. After the first five, `length(mdata)` becomes all 108s. Is there something wrong with my nested loop?

Code:

```
chrdata <- list()
mdata <- list()
res_df <- list()

for(i in 1:24) {
  l <- length(olap[[i]])
  for (j in 1:l) {
    #for each row in granges object
    sub_olap <- as.data.frame(mcols(subsetByOverlaps(all_list, olap[[i]][j]))) 
    chrdata[[j]] <- data.frame(median(sub_olap$log2Ratio), #make metadata a single row and determine median
                   paste0(sub_olap$pvalue, collapse = ","),
                   paste0(sub_olap$length, collapse = ","),
                   paste0(sub_olap$sample, collapse = ","), stringsAsFactors = F)
    colnames(chrdata[[j]]) <- c("med_log2Ratio", "pvalue", "length", "sample")
  }
  mdata[[i]] <- chrdata
  mdf <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(mdata[[i]]), nrow = l, byrow = T))
  colnames(mdf) <- c("med_log2Ratio", "pvalue", "length", "sample")
  res_df[[i]] <- cbind(chr[[i]], mdf)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to create data frame from list, but most terms turn into ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552476/need-to-create-data-frame-from-list-but-most-terms-turn-into-ones)

Comment: Not a duplicate

Comment: Provide us with a minimal reproducible example (data).

Comment: @merryberry it's essentially the same script that you're trying to debug, your problems may be linked, have you solved your issue on the other side ?

Comment: yes, i solved those problems , so the code is is sligthly modified. @moody_mudskipper